# How to create a patch for renaming a file

Tags: rename, diff, patch

Suppose I have a file (`myfile.txt`) containing this text:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I rename this file from `myfile.txt` to `mystory.txt`. How do I create a diff that represents this renaming? How do I create a diff that I can feed to `patch` so that `myfile.txt` is renamed to `mystory.txt`? There are no changes in the contents of the file; only the name of the file is changed.

I am using `diff` from GNU diffutils, and `patch` from GNU patch.

Answer (score 3):

The diff **`-N`** option is used for this:

```
   -N, --new-file                                                           
          treat absent files as empty
```

For example

```
$ mkdir foo
$ ls -l >foo/listing
$ cp -r foo foo2
$ mv foo2/listing foo2/listing2
$ diff -r -N foo foo2 >/tmp/diff
```

will generate a listing showing "foo2/listing" as a new file.

The command-line *`diff`* will not show this as ***renamed***, but as something that patch can delete/add.  It does not show it as a "rename" because diff compares only the *content* of the file, ignores the inode value (which would be preserved when renaming on the same filesystem).  In contrast, `git` (if you use ***its*** renaming feature) will show renames.  **`Git`** can be fooled, of course, but it is a few orders of magnitude more complex than **`diff`**.

Comment: Git can identify renames even if you don’t use its own renaming feature.

Comment: It "can", but I've seen it fail more often than not in that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

GNU patch supports file renaming feature of Git-style diffs, since it's last release in 2012. If you don't want to install Git, you can hand-craft the patch file yourself:

```
diff --git a/myfile.txt b/mystory.txt
similarity index 100%
rename from myfile.txt
rename to mystory.txt
```

And it works well enough:

```
$ ls
myfile.txt  rename.patch

$ patch < rename.patch
patching file myfile.txt (renamed from mystory.txt)

$ ls
mystory.txt  rename.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

Patches can’t directly represent file renames; a rename appears as a file removal and creation. To produce such a patch, you need to have two directories representing the original state and the desired state:

```sh
mkdir a b
echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." > a/myfile.txt
cp a/myfile.txt b/mystory.txt
```

`a` contains the original state, `b` the desired state. To produce a patch, run

```
diff -urN a b > story.patch
```

The `-N` option is necessary because, by default with `-r`, `diff` performs file comparisons: each file is compared pair-wise in the two compared directory hierarchies. A file with no match is listed as “Only in ...” if the `-N` option is omitted; its content is ignored. In this particular case, with `-N`, `diff` sees that `b/myfile.txt` is missing, so it compares `a/myfile.txt` with a virtual empty file, and likewise for `b/mystory.txt`.

Applying this patch will result in the desired state, albeit not by renaming the `myfile.txt` file, but by deleting it and creating `mystory.txt`:

```
patch < story.patch
```

(By default, `patch` skips the first directory in paths specified in a patch.)

Comment: Well, that’s not part of the question ;-). `diff` and `patch` on their own don’t deal with empty files well (which is why `patch` has the `-E` option, to make up for deficiencies in what can be represented in a patch).